# MockMvc get perform returns status 200 but without response body

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, junit, mockmvc

I have an issue with REST Controller testing:

```
@WebMvcTest(PersonController.class) 
public class Testing {
    
    @MockBean
    PersonService personService;
    
    @MockBean
    JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    
    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    
    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username="tester")
    void test() throws Exception {
        PersonGetDTO person1 = new PersonGetDTO(1L,
                "FirstName1",
                "LastName1",
                "img1.png",
                LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2000, 01, 01), LocalTime.of(00, 00))
                );
        PersonGetDTO person2 = new PersonGetDTO(2L,
                "FirstName2",
                "LastName2",
                "img2.png",
                LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2000, 01, 01), LocalTime.of(00, 01))
                );
        List<PersonGetDTO> personList = new ArrayList<>();
        personList.add(person1);
        personList.add(person2);
    
        Pageable pageable = Pageable.unpaged();
    
        Page<PersonGetDTO> persons = new PageImpl<>(personsList, pageable, personList.size());
    
    
        when(personService.getPersons(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok(persons));
            
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/persons"))
                .andDo(print());
    }
}
```

When I run this test I get

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"0", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

Even my status is 200, i have an empty body response, and I can't understand why

My controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/persons")
public class PersonController {

    private final PersonService service;

    @Autowired
    public PersonController(PersonService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @GetMapping
    @Operation(
            summary = "Returns a page of all persons "
    )
    public ResponseEntity<Page<PersonGetDTO>> getPersons(@PageableDefault(page = 0, size = 5, sort = "dateTime", direction = Sort.Direction.DESC) Pageable pageable,
                                                            @AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
        return service.getPersons(pageable, user);

    }
```

My service:

```
public interface PersonService {
    
    ResponseEntity<Page<PersonGetDTO>> getPersons(Pageable pageable, User user);

}
```

P.S. using postman all works and returns valid page of Persons, i guess the problem in using Mockito.when(), but i can't understand where is the mistake

I tried to use different mocks in thenReturn(), but it didn't help

Comment: Try returning only persons: `.thenReturn(persons)`

Comment: that will call wrong type of returning object:

java: no suitable method found for thenReturn(org.springframework.data.domain.Page<com.example.payload.person.PersonGetDTO>)